# httpd conf won't allow apache restart

Tags: apache, sublimetext3

I'm setting up Apache and Home Brew on my local host for Mac Catalina and unable to restart apache after installation. This is the error I'm getting:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 248 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf:
DocumentRoot '/usr/local/opt/httpd/Users/my-computer/Sites' is not a directory, or is not readable
```

I tried to get rid of the quotes around my Document Root info as that seems to be the syntax error? I have checked and the directory does in fact exist.

```
DocumentRoot Users/my-computer/Sites
<Directory Users/my-computer/Sites>
```

I'm opening httpd.conf on sublime3 using zsh via this command:

```
sublime /user/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

Comment: Make sure `/usr/local/opt/httpd/Users/my-computer/Sites` can be read by the user running your Apache instance.  Do an `ls -alp` to see the permissions on the directory.

Comment: @Nic3500 I tried, same issue.